# tabsetPanel within a fluidPage not working

Tags: r, data-visualization, shiny

I'm trying to set up a shiny vis with two panels.

I would also like, within each panel, to use a fluidPage layout, where I can have columns.

I went ahead and attempted this.  But my code isn't working quite right.

I am ending up with one page, where there are 2 tabs, and neither of them work.  Further, neither tab has the text that one would expect to be present.

Here is an screenshot of my shiny app. Note the tabs up on the top, which are doing nothing useful:

[image]

How can I get the tabs to interact properly? Is there any way to have 2 tabs, and within each tab, use the fluidPage functions to create custom rows and columns?

**UI.R**

```
shinyUI(fluidPage(
  titlePanel("Shiny Viz!"),

  mainPanel(

    tabsetPanel(
    fluidRow(
      column(4,
      tabPanel("Controls", checkboxGroupInput("select", label="", choices = list("Age" = "Age", "Weight" = "Weight", "Circumference" = "Circumference"), inline=TRUE))),

      column(4,
      plotOutput("select"))               
               ))),

    tabsetPanel(
    fluidRow(
      column(4,
      tabPanel("output_at_some_point"))))
  ))
```

**SERVER.R**

```
library(shiny)
library(ggplot2)

DF <- as.data.frame(matrix(c(1:9),ncol=3,nrow=3))
DF <- data.frame(replicate(3,1:3))
names(DF) <- c("Age", "Weight", "Circumference")

shinyServer(function(input, output) {  

  output$select <- renderPlot({

    # modify DF
    DF_with_tests_selected <- subset(DF, select = input$select)

    #ggplot
     p <- ggplot(DF)
     p <- p + geom_segment(aes(x=1, xend=1, y=2, yend=3))

    plot(p) 
    }) 
})
```

Comment: Read the help for `tabsetPanel`. `tabsetPanel` can only contain `tabPanel` elements as members of the tabset.

Comment: So it appears that I can't use columns if I want tabs!

Comment: Not sure what you are looking for but maybe `navbarPage` and `navbarMenu` is what you are after.

Answer (score 7):

I am not quite sure that I understand what you expect your app to look like, so I  can't tell you what was wrong with your code. However, I can answer this question:

> Is there any way to have 2 tabs, and within each tab, use the fluidPage functions to create custom rows and columns?

Yes it is possible, see the example. 
Note that I use `fluidRow` instead of the `mainPanel`, but I am not sure if it make much of a difference. Also, this is a single-file shiny app. 
I would put a screenshot off the app, but it seem that I can't.

```
 # UI components.
ui <- fluidPage(
titlePanel("Shiny Viz!"),

fluidRow( class= "R1",
tabsetPanel(type= "pills",

        tabPanel("Controls",
                 fluidRow(column(4, offset=1, selectInput("X", label="x var", 
                                      choices = list("Age" = "Age", "Weight" = "Weight", "Circumference" = "Circumference"),
                                      multiple=F) ),
                          column(4,selectInput("Y", label="y var", 
                                       choices = list("Age" = "Age", "Weight" = "Weight", "Circumference" = "Circumference"),
                                       multiple=F))) ,
                 fluidRow(column(5, offset=1, plotOutput("plot", height = "400px") ),
                          column(5, class= "R2C2", helpText("This is an exemple") ) ) ),
        tabPanel("output_at_some_point",
                 div(style = "height:800px; background-color: yellow;", "This is an example")))  

  ), tags$head(tags$style(".R2C2{height:250px; background-color: red;}
                      .R1{background-color: lightgray;}"))
)



library(ggplot2)
 # Create fake data
DF <- data.frame( Age = rnorm(50, 45, 20), Weight= runif(50, 50 , 200), Circumference =  runif(50, 30 , 100) )  

 # server component
server <- function(input, output) {  
 output$plot <- renderPlot({
   DF$X <- DF[, which(names(DF) == input$X)]
   DF$Y <- DF[, which(names(DF) == input$Y)]   
ggplot(DF, aes( x= X, y= Y)) + geom_point() + labs(list(x = input$X, y = input$Y))
 } )
} 


shinyApp(ui=ui, server=server)
```

Answer (score 1):

Check out the gallery example [here](http://shiny.rstudio.com/gallery/tabsets.html)

I believe you're missing a few things:

```
tabsetPanel(type="tabs",
    tabPanel("name of panel",
```

etc.

Comment: My question must really not be clear. The example in the gallery does not make use of fluidRow or columns. I would like to make use of fluidRow and columns, yet also have tabs.

Comment: @MattO'Brien to be clear `tabsetPanel` contains `tabPanel` elements. `fluidRow` and `columns` would go inside `tabPanel` elements and not reside in the `tabsetPanel` as you have in your example.